# Could I make my program choose randomly between variables (all integers) in a list, with it returning the variable, not the value?

Tags: python, random

So I have a list of variables (all being integers). I would want to randomly choose one of these variables, but make it so that it returns the actual variable, not the value.

for example:

```
list = [a, b, c, d]
```

(with all of them equal to 0)

```
print(random.choice(list))
```

would return 0, while I want it to return a, b, c or d;

So that if I write :

```
random.choice(list) += 2
```

It would update one of these variables.

Comment: You could make a dictionary instead like `d = {'variable':'value'...}`. It seems you want both the name and the value.

Comment: Do you need the list AND the individual names for the elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With python, there are built-in names that should not be repaeted, list happens to be one of these terms. I figure that you used it for the question, but thought to say it anyways because it caused me a headache when I started and couldn't figure out what was wrong.

What it sounds like you are asking is how can I increment an index of a list.

if you have a list:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
# or
zeroes = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

you can change any index by doing this:

```
# nums before being changed:
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
nums[2] += 10  # change 2nd index of the list
# nums after being changed:
# [1, 2, 13, 4]
```

If you randomly want to change the index of the list, you will need to get a random index between 0 and the max index of the list.
Using the random package, you can do this:

```
import random

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]

idx = random.randint(0, len(nums) - 1)

nums[idx] += 10

print(nums)
```

you need to subtract 1 from the length, otherwise it will sometimes return an index 1 larger than the length of your list.

Example outputs:

```
[11, 2, 3, 4]

[1, 2, 13, 4]

[1, 2, 3, 14]
```

Comment: "What it sounds like you are asking is how can I increment an index of a list" - I think they are just confused about how variables and primitives work in python.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead randomly sample an index, then use that to mutate the element

```
>>> import random
>>> values = [3, 6, 8, 2]
>>> values[random.choice(range(len(values)))] += 2
>>> values
[3, 6, 8, 4]
```

Comment: Except they seem to expect the list to contain _references_ to integers (increment value of a list element and observe the change through another name). I'm not a python guy, but I think python doesn't do that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You are correct, that is why I suggested this alternative, this will allow you to modify the values of the list elements directly using a sampled index of that list

Comment: Yep, that's the way I would go about it, but if they also need individual names for the list elements, this won't work (and I'm not sure if it's at all possible in python)